# incoherence in bcp command execution

Tags: sql-server, bcp, sqlbulkcopy

I execute a bcp command in 2 computer. The first computer has windows xp and second one has windows server 2003. when I execute command in first, the bcp run successfully but when I run this on second one, occur this error:

```
Starting copy...
SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Code page 720 is not supp
orted by SQL Server
SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Unable to resolve column level collat
ions

BCP copy out failed
```

what is the problem?

Comment: what is the file encoding like? what is the target table field data type? Code page 720 is for Arabic text. Is your SQL Server table field designed to handle such a text?

Comment: my db so designed to handle persian text.

Comment: Could that be due to client drivers for SQL on windows xp?

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at the following article and play with the switches in you BCP statement.

[Copying Data Between Different Collations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa196742%28SQL.80%29.aspx)